# php query() returns true but does not update database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a form inside a table which dynamically creates rows based on number of records in the database. The form serves to update the records. It works in a separate test file I have created for testing but not when I merge it with actual file.

```
<form role="form" id="edit_form" class="form-inline" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>?action=edit_menu" method="post"></form>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
            <th>Item 1</th>
            <th>Item 2</th>
            <th>Item 3</th>
            <th>Item 4</th>
            <th>Item 5</th>
            <th>Item 6</th>
            <th>Item 7</th>
            <th>Item 8</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
            foreach($menu_items as $key => $value){
                echo "
                <tr>
                    <td>
                    <input type='text' name='name".$count."' form='edit_form' value=".$value["name"].">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <input type='text' name='price".$count."' form='edit_form' value=".$value["price"].">
                    </td> 
                    <td>
                    <select form='edit_form' name='item1".$count."'>
                        <option>".$value["item1"]."</option>";
                        foreach ($db_items as $keys => $values) {
                            echo "<option value=".$values["name"].">".$values["name"]."</option>";
                        }
                echo "
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <select form='edit_form' name='item2".$count."'>
                        <option>".$value["item2"]."</option>";
                        foreach ($db_items as $keys => $values) {
                            echo "<option value=".$values["name"].">".$values["name"]."</option>";
                        }
                echo "
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <select form='edit_form' name='item3".$count."'>
                        <option>".$value["item3"]."</option>";
                        foreach ($db_items as $keys => $values) {
                            echo "<option value=".$values["name"].">".$values["name"]."</option>";
                        }
                echo "
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <select form='edit_form' name='item4".$count."'>
                        <option>".$value["item4"]."</option>";
                        foreach ($db_items as $keys => $values) {
                            echo "<option value=".$values["name"].">".$values["name"]."</option>";
                        }
                echo "
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <select form='edit_form' name='item5".$count."'>
                        <option>".$value["item5"]."</option>";
                        foreach ($db_items as $keys => $values) {
                            echo "<option value=".$values["name"].">".$values["name"]."</option>";
                        }
                echo "
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <select form='edit_form' name='item6".$count."'>
                        <option>".$value["item6"]."</option>";
                        foreach ($db_items as $keys => $values) {
                            echo "<option value=".$values["name"].">".$values["name"]."</option>";
                        }
                echo "
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <select form='edit_form' name='item7".$count."'>
                        <option>".$value["item7"]."</option>";
                        foreach ($db_items as $keys => $values) {
                            echo "<option value=".$values["name"].">".$values["name"]."</option>";
                        }
                echo "
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    <select form='edit_form' name='item8".$count."'>
                        <option>".$value["item8"]."</option>";
                        foreach ($db_items as $keys => $values) {
                            echo "<option value=".$values["name"].">".$values["name"]."</option>";
                        }
                echo "
                    </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type='hidden' name='id".$count."' form='edit_form' value=".$value["id"].">
                        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-xs green-haze' name='count".$count."' form='edit_form' value='Edit'>
                    </td>   
                </tr>"; 
                if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_GET['action'] == 'edit_menu') {
                    if(isset($_POST['count'.$count.''])){

                        $update_menu = "UPDATE `menu` 
                        SET `name`= '".$_POST["name".$count]."',`price`='".$_POST["price".$count]."',`item1`='".$_POST["item1".$count]."',`item2`='".$_POST["item2".$count]."',`item3`='".$_POST["item3".$count]."',`item4`='".$_POST["item4".$count]."',`item5`='".$_POST["item5".$count]."',`item6`='".$_POST["item6".$count]."',`item7`='".$_POST["item7".$count]."',`item8`='".$_POST["item8".$count]."' 
                        WHERE `id`='".$_POST["id".$count]."'";

                        if ($conn->query($update_menu)) {
                            header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                            die;    
                        }
                    }
                }                          
                $count++;
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is the table along with the form I have created in it. There is no problem with the database connection (all other forms are working fine).

There is no error. $conn->query() returns true and executes any statement I place inside the if() with it, but still it doesn't update the database.

I can share the rest of the script if that helps.

Thank You

Comment: Does the form actual submit anything, you close it when you open it. `<form role="form" id="edit_form" class="form-inline" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>?action=edit_menu" method="post"></form>`.

Comment: You are sql injecting yourself?

Comment: @chris85 Funny, I didn't even notice that.

Comment: @jeroen I didn't "swerve" drastically to the right neither *lol*

Comment: *"I can share the rest of the script if that helps."* - You mean there's more??

Comment: @Fred-ii- No, just going down was quite enough ;-)

Comment: @jeroen I'm not quite sure how to take that *hahaha!!!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ummmmmmm

Comment: @Chris yes it works. There is a form attribute in all the input and select tags. It works fine in a separate file, just not when I put it in the actual file.

Comment: @jeroen yes there is more. This web page has other forms in it as well. They all work fine.

Comment: Oh HTML5 atts. Well  `foreach($menu_items as $key => $value){` does nothing with `$count` so your `where` is probably not what you expect it to be. Output the query and see what you actually are executing. A failed query and a query that has not results are different.

Comment: @chris85 You are right. The `$count` wasnt being sent to sql query. I didnt include the 'id' from the database into the `$menu_items`, so it was empty.